# how do i define the innerHTML in a ts file and call it in an html file in angular 4?

Tags: angular, ionic3

The following block of code is in my html file currently but i want to define it inside the corresponding ts file and then call it in my html file using the innerHTML.

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Baseplan Roster</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <div padding center text-center>
      <h3>Base Plan Roster</h3>   
<div innerHTML = > // I want to just call the innerHTML here which defines the below code(ion-slides block), this code should be placed in the ts file and not here below inside the ts file.

        <ion-slides  pager="true" id="slides">
                  <ion-slide *ngFor ="let st of obj">
                    <h3>{{rost.dayOfTheWeek}}</h3>
                    <ion-item *ngFor= "let m of st.segment">
                    <h2>lets </h2>
                    <h2>({{m.name}})</h2>
                    <h3>Grade:
                      <b>{{m.grade}}</b>
                    </h3>
                    <h3>On Date:
                      <b>{{m.OnDate}}</b>
                    </h3>
                    <h3>Off Date:
                      <b>{{m.OffDate}}</b>
                    </h3>
                  </ion-item>
                  </ion-slide>
                </ion-slides>

</div>
</ion-content>



        Currently my ts file looks like this:

        import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
        import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, LoadingController, Loading, Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

         @IonicPage()
            @Component({
              selector: 'page-manager-details',
              templateUrl: 'manager-details.html',
            })
            export class ManagerDetailsPage {

          unFit: fitModel[] = [];
          fit: fitModel[] = [];
          default: fitModel[] = [];


              constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private crewProvider: 
                         CrewProvider, public navParams: NavParams,
                         public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public utils: 
                         UtilsModule) {

            showLoading() {

                this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
                  content: 'Loading Data'
                });

                this.loading.present();
              } 

              ionViewDidLoad() {

              this.obj = this.navParams.data.rosterDetails;

                  for (let mainData of this.obj ) {

                    for(let newData of mainData.status){
                      if (newData.condition == 'Fit') {
                        this.fit.push(newData);
                      }

                      if (newData.condition == 'Not Fit') {
                        this.notFit.push(newData);
                      }
                      if (newData.condition == 'Default') {
                        this.default.push(newData);
                      }
                    }

                    this['unFit'+mainData.dayOfTheWeek] = this.unFit;
                    this['Fit'+mainData.dayOfTheWeek] = this.Fit; 
                    this['default'+mainData.dayOfTheWeek] = this.default; 

                   // i want to define the innerHTML here.

                    this.unFit = [];
                    this.fit = [];
                    this.default = [];
            } 
        }    

   }
```

Please assist how i can define my html code block(ion-slide code block) inside the ts file and call it inside the html file using the innerHTML tag.

Comment: This wont work for non standard html tags (like ion-slides). Why not use ngIf or other conditionals inside your template code?

Comment: @Sergey Rudenko thanks for your advice i really appreciate it. may you please elaborate with code example how i can make use of conditionals to accomplish my desired results.

Comment: @JGFMK do you have any idea of how this can be achieved?

Comment: Can you share the html code you wanted to generate for all 3 cases? Then it would be easier to help u

Comment: @Sergey Rudenko the html is shared in my code, look for <ion-slides></ion-slides> section in the code i shared initially.